# <div> element does not adhere to the Display: inline property

Tags: html, css, inline, display

I am new to web development and I am facing an issue. I want to display three div's next to each other. So, I applied `display:inline-block` to the three div's. But, still the Div's are stacked one below another and not next to each other.

Codepen link: https://codepen.io/shanjaynithin/pen/XWmBPYd

Desired output:
[Sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RVGCb.png)

Comment: Simply displaying them inline-block doesn't force them to fit. They're expanding to contain the text inside, which results in them having a cumulative width over 100%.

Comment: @Shanjay would you mind accepting it as answer if you think if it is worth doing it! thanks.

Comment: Ya sure, but how to accept?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `flex` for this:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.boxes {
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

img{
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
}
```

```html
  <div class="container">
   <div class="boxes">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/301/301" alt="snappy-process">
    <h3>Snappy Process</h3>
    <p>Our application process can be completed in minutes, not hours. Don’t get
    stuck filling in tedious forms.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="boxes">
    <img class="eg" src="http://placekitten.com/301/301" alt="affordable-prices">
    <h3 >Affordable Prices</h3>
    <p>We don’t want you worrying about high monthly costs. Our prices may be low,
    but we still offer the best coverage possible.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="boxes">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/301/301" alt="people-first">
    <h3>People First</h3>
    <p>Our plans aren’t full of conditions and clauses to prevent payouts. We make
    sure you’re covered when you need it.</p>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Can you give an explanation as why does inline not work here?

Comment: for inline-block to work you have to specify width for ex. 33% consdering you have 3 divs, so instead if you use `flex` that will take care of space evenly by default and works for responsiveness as well. Without using width for inline-block will take entire row.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    width: 100vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="boxes">
        <img src="images/icon-snappy-process.svg" alt="snappy-process">
        <h3>Snappy Process</h3>
        <p>Our application process can be completed in minutes, not hours. Don’t get
            stuck filling in tedious forms.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="boxes">
        <img class="eg" src="images/icon-affordable-prices.svg" alt="affordable-prices">
        <h3>Affordable Prices</h3>
        <p>We don’t want you worrying about high monthly costs. Our prices may be low,
            but we still offer the best coverage possible.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="boxes">
        <img src="images/icon-people-first.svg" alt="people-first">
        <h3>People First</h3>
        <p>Our plans aren’t full of conditions and clauses to prevent payouts. We make
            sure you’re covered when you need it.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Can you give an explanation as why does inline not work here?

Comment: It can do without flex, Remove container class and add this .boxes {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 30%;
} But important thing is flex is very easy to use further when we doing further developments.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="app">
 <div>One</div>
 <div>Two</div>
 <div>Three</div>
</div>

#app div{
float: left;
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
border: 1px solid;
}
```

Comment: Very basic snippet. You can use float elegantly & use % for achieving anything.

Comment: good that you shared your inputs, however now the `float` has become very old and it is not worth using for responsiveness so you can still move the code to `flex` and make it easy. Cheers.